# Getting taxanomy value from URL

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm setting up a search page by views exposed filter. And one of the field are filter by taxonomy term.

For example, when I search with the taxonomy term filter field, the URL is like below.

domain.com/search?subjects=69

Now I wish to get the value of the taxonomy (it's showing tid instead of value)

```
<?php
$idenity = $_GET['subjects'];
print $idenity;
?>
```

Anyway to get the value of the taxonomy value but not taxonomy id?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version you're using so I'm assuming Drupal 7 because it's the latest stable version.

You can load the term with `taxonomy_term_load()`:

```
<?php
$tid = intval($_GET['subjects']);
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid)
print $term->name;
?>
```

Personally, I find that the comments on the [Drupal API site](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7) are usually very helpful in understanding how to use functions that sound like they are relevant to my problem.

Comment: There's a similar function called taxonomy_term_load_multiple() that takes an array as argument.

Comment: tested, and looks like intval() is causing my page to crash

Comment: intval() will not work with taxonomy_term_load_multiple(), no. That's because intval creates a single integer value. Doesn't work with arrays.

Why did you unmark my original answer as correct to your original question?

Comment: as i tested and it gives me error for intval(). not with multiple load.